# GitHub CLI approve Pull Request as different user in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, github-cli

I have GitHub action that approves a Pull Request:

```yaml
      - name: Approve a PR
        run: gh pr review --approve "$PR_URL"
        env:
          PR_URL: ${{github.event.pull_request.html_url}}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

When action runs approval is performed by `github-actions`. Is there any way to perform `gh pr review --approve` as different user?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to perform a `gh auth login` with a different user in the step before running the `gh pr review` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just use a token for a different user in `GITHUB_TOKEN` field.